# How to fix the error of making a static reference to a non-static method using array lists

Tags: java, class, object, compiler-errors

at the moment I am just doing some practise in java:

Main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import settelersofcatan.playerinformation;

public class settlersofcatanhelper 
{
     private ArrayList<playerinformation> PlayerArray = new ArrayList<playerinformation>();
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
         String NumberOfPlayersString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many player");
         int NumberOfPlayers = Integer.parseInt(NumberOfPlayersString);


         for (int Counter = 0; Counter < NumberOfPlayers; Counter++)
         {
             String Name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name of player " + Counter);
             String Colour = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("which colour are you playing with");
             playerinformation PlayerDetails = new playerinformation(Name, Colour, Counter);
             addplayer(PlayerDetails);
         }

     }

    public void addplayer(playerinformation player)
    {
    this.PlayerArray.add(player);
    }
}
```

Helper Class:

```
package settelersofcatan;

public class playerinformation {
    String PlayerName;
    String Colour;
    int Position;

    public playerinformation(String name, String colour, int position) 
    {
        setPlayerName(name);
        setColour(colour);
        setPosition(position);

    }

    public String getPlayerName() {
        return PlayerName;
    }
    public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
        PlayerName = playerName;
    }
    public String getColour() {
        return Colour;
    }
    public void setColour(String colour) {
        Colour = colour;
    }
    public int getPosition() {
        return Position;
    }
    public void setPosition(int position) {
        Position = position;
    }
}
```

The Problem that I am having now is that I am trying to add a player's information and get the response "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method addplayer(playerinformation) from the type settlersofcatanhelper".
I have looked over the code where I have this working but cant see any difference or reason why it wouldnt work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `public void addplayer(playerinformation player)` is non-static, but you're calling it from `main` (which is `static`). Read the duplicate, and/or information on `static` in Java.

Comment: @notyou Will give it a read and see if it helps me

Comment: @notyou, I understand that but how can I make it work then, do I have to make seperate method for it?

Comment: You must understand what static means to begin with. It basically means that it's independent and is not relied on the class's state at any point. By having a static method referencing a property in the class and interfering with it essentially makes it reliant on the state of the class and is therefor not a valid static method and will thus fail.

Comment: At a glance you could make `addplayer` static, but then you'd need to make `PlayerArray` static too, which might not be what you want. Oh, and `this` probably will give the same error too, in `addplayer`, so you can use `settlersofcatanhelper.PlayerArray.add(player);`. But I would still read up on `static` and figure it out. Also, please look up Java naming conventions (class begins with capital letter, variables are camelCase etc).

Comment: sorry @notyou, forgot that stackoverflow hides comments when the replies go over a certain limit, so only saw your comment now

Comment: @notyou, upon using your solution it gives the error twice since I think that settelers of catan is also static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand what the word "static" means. 
You can look here among other places: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html (documentation)
https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java (easy to read tutorial)

> If you apply static keyword with any method, it is known as static method.
>   A static method belongs to the class rather than object of a class.
>   A static method can be invoked without the need for creating an instance of a class.
>   static method can access static data member and can change the value of it.

So, You cannot call a non-static (object) method from a static (class) method. You need to create an object and call the method on the object reference:

```
settlersofcatanhelper a = new settlersofcatanhelper();
a.addPlayer(PlayerDetails);
```

or change the method to a static one if that's what You want to do (not for me to judge, depends on what You're trying to achieve), but keep in mind `this` variable cannot be called from static content (the list itself would also have to be static).

```
private static ArrayList<playerinformation> PlayerArray = new ArrayList<playerinformation>();

[...]

public static void addplayer(playerinformation player) {
    this.PlayerArray.add(player);
}
```

"
Also (not entirely on the topic), I suggest You read about naming conventions in java :)

edit:

My idea to try and get a grasp of it is to create a separate class (call it "Test" or whatever) with the `public static void main(String[] args)` method (and nothing else), and start from there. The difference between static and non-static members may be a little bit confusing in the beginning, and having a separate place for your "logic" may be helpful to distinguish what you can and cannot use from static content.

then your `main` method could look something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    settlersofcatanhelper object = new settlersofcatanhelper();
    // do what you want with your object (which is an instance of settlersofcatanhelper class)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input. I am just not entirely sure how to fix my program in particular. I created an object at the start of my public class settlersofcatanhelper and i still get the error, I dont really know where to go from there?

Comment: and yes, I will read up on the Java naming conventions, but I first wanted to get the program working before I made it neat.

Comment: @Outlander I gave a solution in my comment under your post, which will remove the errors, but be very sure it's what you want regarding `static` methods and variables.

Comment: @notyou, I do understand what you meant, but I just don't understand how I could then make the program work the way I wanted, instead of just removing the error

Comment: @Outlander the problem here is that You in fact never create any instance of settlersofcatanhelper - I think some reading on a difference between a class and an object is the way to go https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/HLUs/User_Guide/classes/classoview.shtml

The problem here is that You are trying to use an object method from within a class method.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a non-static method(addplayer) from a static one(main). You can fix it, just make *addplayer* static.

Comment: Wouldnt that just lock up

Answer (score 0):

The `main` method is static; the `addplayer` method is an instance method. Therefore you need an instance of `settlersofcatanhelper` in order to call `addplayer` on it.

Comment: so would I have to make one main class that calls it, to make it non-static?

Comment: No, You can do it within the same class, but it is really less confusing to make a separate one. Also it is a better practice, as this gives each class a single responsibility.